# Vuex: Referencing specific state data in getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have to pull in data from 12 specific departments. When my Vue store gets mounted, I fire off some actions to load in these orders via 12 different ajax calls. (These calls are to different API end points and servers).

Once I get a response I commit them to the state. So in my state I would have the following data set to arrays:

```js
state: {
  sportsOrders: [],
  photographicOrders: []
  //And more..
},
```

Now I need to filter these specific orders based on if they are late, in production, etc. So I have a getter that is setup like so:

```js
getters: {
  getDepartmentLateOrders: (state) => (department) => {
    let resultArray = []
    state.department.forEach(function(order, index) {
      let now = new Date()
      let orderShipDate = new Date(order.ExpectedShipDate)
      let diff = date.getDateDiff(orderShipDate, now)
      if(diff < 0) {
        resultArray.push(order)
      }
    })
    return resultArray
  },
}
```

And then when I need to use it in a component...

```js
return this.$store.getters.getDepartmentLateOrders(this.department+'Orders')

//for example it will end up passing 'sportsOrders' to the getter
```

However, when I do this, Vue doesn't use the state data for `sportsOrders` so I know I'm not accessing it correctly. It says:
`vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:574 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"`

If I hardcode my getter like so it works as expected though (but I don't want to do this for 12 departments)..

```js
state.sportsOrders.forEach(function(order, index) {
...
}
```

How can I set this up so I can use this one getter and have it work with all 12 departments? I only want to pass the name of the department if possible.

Comment: Try `state[department].forEach(`

Comment: Works! Wow. I knew it would be something small like that